# how to get file under projectname.resources in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, resources, classloader

I am trying to get (read from) a file, that is under "resources" folder. My project structure is:

Project1

--Source Packages

--package1

```
--Class1
--Class2
```

--package1.resources

```
---foo.text
```

I need to use data from foo.text into Class1 (has main method), but I am not able to get foo.text from "package1.resources", So far I have tried,

```
final String resourcesPath = "package1.resources/foo.text";
InputStream stream = Class1.class.getResourceAsStream(resourcesPath);
//In this case stream comes null

 File file = new File(getClass().getResource("package1.resources").getFile());
//in this case file comes null
```

I'm stuck at this point. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

For the path you have to use `/` instead of `dot(.)`
For the ressource extension you can use `dot(.)`

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/package1/resources/foo.text").getFile());
//-------------------------------------------^--------^---------^---^
```